# Abusive traffic to DNS server generating request for "linksys.secureshellz.net"

Tags: security, dns, malware

My server has blocked by netadmin by the following reason

"We are seeing abusive traffic from your machine to our DNS server.  It is generating many DNS requests for "linksys.secureshellz.net".  See below for sample traffic."

Example traffic:

```
2014-05-27
Time (PDT)      Source                Destination           Protocol-Info
12:11:51.124767 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0x1de7  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.125005 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0x1de7 No such name
12:11:51.125216 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0xe1a2  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.125456 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0xe1a2 No such name
12:11:51.125635 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0x415c  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.125908 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0x415c No such name
12:11:51.126115 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0x8413  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.126429 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0x8413 No such name
12:11:51.126608 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0xb2c8  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.126760 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0xb2c8 No such name
12:11:51.126962 164.67.194.217        128.97.10.2           DNS      Standard query 0x4a7b  A linksys.secureshellz.net
12:11:51.127214 128.97.10.2           164.67.194.217        DNS      Standard query response 0x4a7b No such name
```

I've no idea what's going on and I tried command `crontab -l` but found nothing scheduled to download script or something similar. Now what I'm doing is like searching for the keyword "secureshellz" in the whole machine with the command `grep -r "secureshellz" /` and it has been searched 20mins but found nothing.

I'm completely have no experience in computer security issue so can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

First be sure it is generated from your machine 
- fire wireshark ( put "dns" as filter) then check the traffic.

Find the process generating the UDP datagrams

> install auditctl

- - `apt-get install auditctl`

> insert a rule to filter the system call socket

- - `auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1=2 -S socket -k SOCKET`

> Search for the process pid

- - `ausearch -i -ts today -k SOCKET`

> For each process ausearch identified look for the one generating the
>   malicious query

-- `strace -p $YOURPID -f -e trace=network -o trace_$YOURPID`

> You may wan to kill the process and delete all the files related to
>   it, THEN FIND OUT HOW YOU GOT INFECTED AND PATCH THE SYSTEM IF
>   REQUIRED.

**BTW:  SEND ME THE MALEWARE I WOULD LOVE THE REVERSE ENGINEER IT ... :D**